# Bootstrap Progressbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I seem to be having an issue with the bootstrap progress bar.

I have my html set up like so:

```
<div class="progress">
        <div id="progressPlaceholder"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Later on, I generate the progress bar dynamically like so:

```
progress = '<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="'+rank+'" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: '+rank+'%;"><span class="show" id="totalUsers">Ranked '+place+' of </span>';
$('#progressPlaceholder').empty().append(progress);
```

It doesnt add the progress bar it self to the div, just the background that the bar fills up.

Is there something that needs to be run to have it update or re-trigger the progress bar once its added to the DOM?

Comment: Does it work if you replace rank and place with integers?

Comment: It seems to work fine when the progess-bar DIV is properly closed: http://bootply.com/96130

Comment: I must have missed a closing div some where, that took care of it! Thanks for the example :)